# Remotely Send Variable and Run Python Script

Tags: python, ssh, remote-access

So here is the situation..

I have a local computer A and remote computer B.

Computer A has script a.py
Computer B has script b.py

Script a has variables x and y. Let's say x = 5, and y = 10.

I am running a.py on Computer A, and the output is x = 5, y = 10.
I want to ssh or pass these values or variables to b.py and run b.py on Computer B at the same time.

Is it possible?If yes, can you anyone please help me with this.
Thank you!!

Comment: To quote a manager of mine, "anything is possible ... it's just software." :)

Answer (score 0):

You could run b.py remotely on Computer B via ssh with x and y as program arguments like this:

```
os.system('sshpass -p \'Bpassword\' ssh root@MachineB \'python3 b.py {} {}\''.format(x, y))
```

Comment: Where to add this piece of line?In a.py or b.py?

Comment: In a.py when you'll want to run b.py with x and y variables.

Comment: ok..thanks..I am going to try this now..and I will see if I can get out of it what I want.

Comment: I am not using internet, I am using UART cable to serial communication as of now, but for the real communication between Computers A and B, I am using radios? So I believe, now SSH won't be involved. How can I still get this task done? I am using "SCREEN" instead of SSH. Any help there?

Comment: Ok so I am doing the following..

os.system('screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200\' python b.py {} {}\' ' .format(x, y))

Comment: its getting into the remote computer "B" but it is not executing the script b.py and neither the values of variables are getting passed.